# Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: java, json, gson, ambari

I am writing a JAVA code to update the configuration in Ambari.

In Ambari server log, I keep getting following message "Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2"

At client side, I get following error HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error

Following is my JAVA code excerpt:

```
properties.put("Config_name","5096");

JSONObject desired_config = new JSONObject();
desired_config.put("type","service-master");
desired_config.put("tag","version15689870358181");
desired_config.put("service_config_version_note","New config version curl 1");
desired_config.put("properties", properties);

JSONObject Clusters = new JSONObject();
Clusters.put("desired_config", desired_config);

JSONObject UClusters = new JSONObject();
UClusters.put("Clusters", Clusters);

String jsonStr = UClusters.toString();
System.out.println("here it goes\n" + jsonStr);

StringEntity params = new StringEntity(jsonStr);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonStr));

CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

Ambari side JSON is huge file, however it's standard one. Let me know, if this is required to help me out.

Below curl command works fine, and I am trying to have same JSON format in my java code.

`curl -u admin:admin -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -X PUT -d '{"Clusters":{"desired_config":{"type":"service-master","tag":"version156898703582004","properties":{"Config_name":"3096"},"service_config_version_note":"New config version curl 1"}}}' "http://[IP Address]:8080/api/v1/clusters/cluster1"`

My goal is to write a JAVA program to push / update configuration in Ambari.I believe we can use any service for testing / discussion like YARN.

Editing to add this code, which is in String format.

```
System.out.println(json);
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(json);
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(json.toString()));
```

At Ambari side, it gives me "Stack information should be provided when creating a cluster"

Comment: Why are you using Gson at all if you're manually manipulating all of the structure? To your question directly, you are showing the _client_ code that constructs the JSON object referred to in the message but not what the _server_ is expecting (which is apparently a JSON string, in quotes).

Comment: please do not post code in comments. [edit] the question and post it instead